# LinearLayout onShow it moves the ScrollView down

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I want to display my **notification_bar_linearlayout** on top of the **ScrollView**.

In code after the data in **ScrollView** has been populate I will then show the **notification_bar_linearlayout**.

But When I show:

```
notification_bar_linearlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The data inside the **ScrollView** will auto scroll to the middle.
Meaning that in the screen it will have as visible the following:

*notification_bar_linearlayout*

*block_two*

Therefor **block_one** is no longer visible.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            //Notification bar
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/notification_bar_linearlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/white_color"
                android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                android:paddingRight="20dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                android:visibility="gone">
                 <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    //My TextView for the bar
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            //List datas 
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/block_one"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        //My frist block for the top of the list
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/block_two"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        //My second  block for the bottom of the list
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

P.S. There reason for so many LinearLayout is because I have some custom data showing horizontal and others vertical.

Comment: Is seems your code working good. onething block1 completely not visible or scrollview scroll to block 2 & block 1 stay at top.

Comment: it would be great if you can post result vs expected result

Answer (score 0):

Without a screenshot is difficult of understand but maybe you need to set weight in this manner:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            //Notification bar
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:id="@+id/notification_bar_linearlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/white_color"
                android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                android:paddingRight="20dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                android:visibility="gone">
                 <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    //My TextView for the bar
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            //List datas 
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/block_one"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        //My frist block for the top of the list
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/block_two"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        //My second  block for the bottom of the list
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```